# Adding custom routes inside a Firebase instance

Tags: firebase

I'm still new to Firebase (as well as other JS frameworks) and actively reading through the documentation.

As far as I've read, Firebase can take care of basic CRUD operations (be it using the API libraries or directly calling the host URL to the specific route). In my application, I want to create a personal URL route that will handle some business operations and from there, call the CRUD operations.

What I've currently thought of is for me to have a "middleware" that will handle this custom URL routes and Firebase API calls. But since this is outside of the Firebase instance, I can't use its Authentication feature from there.

Is there a way for me to add these custom API calls inside the Firebase instance? I've already searched beforehand and couldn't find any articles regarding the subject.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of putting middleware between Firebase and the user. While it is possible, it complicates matters considerable and you'll quickly lose some of Firebase's biggest advantages (e.g. realtime synchronization, the simplicity of not hosting an API).

Have a look at this classic [blog post on common application architectures with Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-03-25-where-does-firebase-fit.html). Your best bet is likely option 2, where you use the database as your API/endpoint and then run a small (e.g. node or JVM) process to perform the actual operation. A huge advantage of this approach is that these worker processes are often a lot simpler than if they'd run on the middleware, since they are not an API endpoint.

Our [firebase-queue library](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-queue) was made for this type of situation, but [Flashligh](https://github.com/firebase/flashlight) is also a good example.

Comment: I believe I was able to implement something similar Pattern 2 architecture, Thank you for the insight! I've used a Jersey instance for my server which has the endpoints. Inside the endpoints, I use Verify ID of the Firebase Web SDK before doing the CRUD operations. On the client-side, I use Firebase Authentication primarily and it calls my endpoints. It currently works for me but I'll see what I can do to fully implement Pattern 2.