# Custom Endpoints for Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage, endpoints

We want to use Firebase Realtime Database, Firebase Storage, and Firebase Server SDK in a project.

How can we expose this project using custom endpoints which can be used in Android, ios, and web?

**Edit**

After further research I understand that it might not be a good idea to put Firebase behind an endpoint, because that architecture defeats the whole philosophy of Firebase.

But now the issue is that there is no default integration between Firebase Storage and Firebase Realtime Database. Is there a way for server side integration between the two, and the app engine for any custom server side work?

Comment: I believe I asked a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37083824/adding-custom-routes-inside-a-firebase-instance) previously. There's a common architecture that was suggested to use Firebase between the server and client code.

Comment: The architecture suggested in the blog post is of the year 2013 after which several changes have been made in Firebase including integration with Google Cloud platform.

Comment: I found a more recent architectural guidelines https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#firebase

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few common ways of having a project that uses Firebase for its back-end, but that also has custom back-end code running.

Two of the most common ones:

- You can put the database between the app and the back-end. This one was covered in a [blog post in 2013](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/03/where-does-firebase-fit-in-your-app.html), but it is still valid today.
  [image: diagram of Firebase Database between front-end and back-end]
  The [article from the Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#firebase-appengine-flexible) also covers this pattern, with a more modern diagram:

[image: diagram of Firebase Database between front-end and back-end]

- You can [use cloud endpoints and have your app talk directly to the back-end](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/mobile/mobile-app-backend-services#appengine-endpoints).

  [image: diagram of front-end talking to cloud endpoints]

  You'll note that Firebase is not present in this diagram, but your endpoints could talk to Firebase or any other services.

Comment: While this answers the original question, further investigation is required for the ideal architecture.